# Why is the Kolmogorov-Smirnov (Uniform) metric defined by $\sup$ rather than $\max$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let's say we have two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$. Then the Kolmogorov-Smirnov metric $K(X,Y)$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
K(X,Y):=\sup_{t}\{|F_{X}(t)-F_{Y}(t)|:t\in\Bbb R\},
\end{equation}
where $F_{X}$ and $F_{Y}$ are the distribution functions of $X$ and $Y$, respectively.  In every textbook I have looked in, $K$ is always defined in terms of the supremum absolute distance between the two cdfs.  That said, it seems that this is **(always?)** equal to the absolute maximum difference between the two cdfs, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
K(X,Y)=\max_{t}\{|F_{X}(t)-F_{Y}(t)|:t\in\Bbb R\}.
\end{equation}

**Are both expressions above for $K(X,Y)$ equivalent? If so, why is it not defined in terms of $\max$ instead of $\sup$? If not, could you provide an example where the two give different solutions for $K$?**

Comment: They are equivalent. The maximum, if it exists, is equal to the supremum. A standard argument would prove the existence of maximum. As for your question "why is it not defined in terms of max instead of sup", we need some argument to show that the maximum exists, while the supremum always exists.

Comment: @CaveJohnson Ok. So for example if $F_{X}(t)=F_{Y}(t)\,\forall t\in\Bbb R$ then the maximum does not exist but the $\sup$ distance does and is equal to zero? Would this be an example of why $\sup$ is used rather than $\max$, i.e. so that $K$ always exists?